# drupal_set_message on node edit page shows twice with theme hook

Tags: theming, forms

I want to display a value of a field which the user has no access to in a dsm when the user edits the page. The dsm is showing up after saving the node, and while that's fine (I'd even consider it a feature) it's showing the before-edit value of the node.

I believe I've run into [this problem](http://drupal.org/node/988072) but there doesn't seem to be an easy fix. Here's a look at the `template.php` function.

```
function themename_form_vakature_node_form_alter(&$form){
    if(isset($form['#node']->field_vacature_scheduled_for_unp)){
        if($form['#node']->field_vacature_scheduled_for_unp['und'][0]['value']){
            $expirydate = date("F j Y",$form['#node']->field_unpublish_date['und'][0]['value']);

            if($form['#node']->field_unpublish_date['und'][0]['value'] < time()){
                drupal_set_message(t("This vacature has expired."),'status',FALSE);
            }
            else{
                drupal_set_message(t("This vacature will expire at: ").$expirydate,'status',FALSE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the message displayed on the edit page is repeated after a save. I need it to either not repeat or show the correct updated information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form alter changes the form when it's being built for display.

If you want to use the value on the node after update, use a hook like

- [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) or
- [hook_node_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7)

instead.

To tweak your code snippet, something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave
 */
function mymodule_node_presave($node){
  if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_vacature_scheduled_for_unp')) {
    $vacature = reset($items); // Use first field item value
    $expirydate = date("F j Y", $vacature['value']);
    $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_unpublish_date')
    $unpublish = reset($items); // Use first field value
    if ($unpublish['value'] < time()) {
      drupal_set_message(t("This vacature has expired."), 'status', FALSE);
    }
    else{
      drupal_set_message(t("This vacature will expire at: "). $expirydate, 'status', FALSE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising but how would I show the value on the edit page without it appearing twice (That's more important than getting it to show after saving)

Comment: If you want to show the message when the user goes to edit the node, use hook_node_load instead and check if on edit page, e.g arg(0) == 'node' and arg(2) == 'edit'

Comment: Thanks! I'll still have to do some work to get things working properly but I should be able to get it from here!

Comment: By the way, is there a way to do this in the theme rather than a module?

Comment: `hook_node_load` triggers twice while saving the node. Now I have 2x the old value and 1x the new one.